# `updater` not working correctly when using subscriptions in Relay Modern

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relayjs, graphql-subscriptions

I'm using Relay Modern in my app and have successfully integrated subscriptions using the [`requestSubscription`](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/subscriptions.html) function. All works well and the `updater` function that I use to update the cache gets called correctly with the proper subscription payload.

The subscription is used to add a new item to a list of `Link` elements. Here's what the subscription looks like:

#### NewLinkSubscription.js

```
const newLinkSubscription = graphql`
  subscription NewLinkSubscription {
    Link {
      mutation
      node {
        id
        description
        url
        createdAt
        postedBy {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

export default (updater, onError) => {

  const subscriptionConfig = {
    subscription: newLinkSubscription,
    variables: {},
    updater,
    onError
  }

  requestSubscription(
    environment,
    subscriptionConfig
  )

}
```

I then have a `LinkList` component that's rendering all the `Link` elements. In `componentDidMount` of that component, I initiate the `NewLinkSubscription`:

#### LinkList.js

```
class LinkList extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    NewLinkSubscription(
      proxyStore => {
        const createLinkField = proxyStore.getRootField('Link')
        const newLink = createLinkField.getLinkedRecord('node')
        const viewerProxy = proxyStore.get(this.props.viewer.id)
        const connection = ConnectionHandler.getConnection(viewerProxy, 'LinkList_allLinks')
        if (connection) {
          ConnectionHandler.insertEdgeAfter(connection, newLink)
        }
      },
      error => console.log(`An error occured:`, error),
    )
  }

  render() {
    console.log(`LinkList - render `, this.props.viewer.allLinks.edges)
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.viewer.allLinks.edges.map(({node}) =>
          {
            console.log(`render node: `, node)
            return <Link key={node.id} link={node} viewer={this.props.viewer} />
          }
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default createFragmentContainer(LinkList, graphql`
  fragment LinkList_viewer on Viewer {
    id
    ...Link_viewer
    allLinks(last: 100, orderBy: createdAt_DESC) @connection(key: "LinkList_allLinks", filters: []) {
      edges {
        node {
          ...Link_link
        }
      }
    }
  }
`)
```

Now, here's what's happening when a subscription with a new `Link` comes in. The `updater` is called correctly and it seems like the new node gets inserted into the connection correctly (at least `ConnectionHandler.insertEdgeAfter(connection, newLink)` is called).

This triggers a rerender of the component. When I debug `render` to inspect the data (`props.viewer.allLinks.edges`), I can see that a new node indeed was added to the connection - so the list actually does contain one more item now! However, the problem is that this new node is actually `undefined` which causes the app to crash!

[image]

Does anyone spot what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make it work, this is how I implemented the `updater` now:

```
NewLinkSubscription(
  proxyStore => {
    const linkField = proxyStore.getRootField('Link')
    const newLink = linkField.getLinkedRecord('node')
    const viewerProxy = proxyStore.get(this.props.viewer.id)
    const connection = ConnectionHandler.getConnection(viewerProxy, 'LinkList_allLinks', {
      last: 100,
      orderBy: 'createdAt_DESC'
    })
    if (connection) {
      const edge = ConnectionHandler.createEdge(proxyStore, connection, newLink, 'allLinks')
      ConnectionHandler.insertEdgeBefore(connection, edge)
    }
  },
  error => console.log(`An error occurred:`, error),
)
```